# Detect when MVC5 jquery validation as has passed all tests

Tags: asp.net, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using plain vanilla client side validation of my MVC5/Bootstrap3/Jquery validation form, and I would like to present a spinner om submission - but only if all validation has passed.

Is that possible?

TIA
S. Dalby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by hooking to the form's **submit** *event*, and then check if the form is valid.

```
$(function () {
    $('#myForm').submit(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.valid()) {
            // show loading, spinner, whatever.
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I just had to copy/paste your code, thanks a bunch :)